# is there any possible way to deploy automatically to a machine connected to the network ( no ssh access)

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a nodejs app and my question is there any possible way **to deploy automatically (CI/DI) to a machine connected to the network ( no ssh access) that doesn't have a public IP address,**

I've read there's a way with Capistrano or GitHub actions, something like the server pulls the latest version from Github/bitbucket ... and do some actions, but in my case, I need the same but with **a machine connected to the network ( no ssh access) that doesn't have a public IP address**

Comment: Absolutely, you just need to use a pull-based CD (which is actually preferred in general) - where most simple way would be to just set up a cron job on the target node. Then depending on technology you use, there are specialized tools to achieve this, such as Argo CD on Kubernetes - see my article here for a complete sample: https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: After some research, I found the  pull-based CD it requires Kubernetes to implement, in my case I have a Nodejs project, there's no docker or Kubernetes implemented

Comment: As I mentioned above, in the simplest case all you need is a system cron on the target node. Note that most tutorials these days will be about Kubernetes because of its adoption rate.